# Recursively find and return key and value from nested dictionaries python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

Could someone help me with my code below?

This is originally meant to work with data in a json file but I have converted it to work with a json / dictionary variable.

**Right now the get_data_value() function is working but instead of just returning the value, I would like to return a singular dict containing the key and value.**

I am just not sure how to convert the item_generator function to make this possible without ruining the recursion; I found this function from an example here on stackoverflow.

```
def get_data_value(data,data_name):
    d = data['test']
    print(item_generator(d,data_name))
    for _ in item_generator(d,data_name):
        return (_)
    
def item_generator(json_input, lookup_key):
    if isinstance(json_input, dict):
        for key, value in json_input.items():
            if key == lookup_key:  
                data_single_item = {key:value}  # what i want to return
                print(data_single_item)       
                
                yield value                    # only value is returned
            else:
                yield from item_generator(value, lookup_key)
    elif isinstance(json_input, list):
        for item in json_input:
            yield from item_generator(item, lookup_key)
            

json_data = { "test": [ { "Tier1": [ { "Tier1-Main-Title-1": [ { "title": "main", "example": 400 } ] } ] }, { "Tier2": [] }, { "Tier3": [ { "Example1-Sub1": 44 } ] } ] }

print(get_data_value(json_data,'title'))
```

Comment: If the code is the exact same, it'd be preferable to remove the external link, as not needed anyway :-)

Comment: Also, whats the point of the `item_generator` function here? meaning, would we be required to use it?

Comment: item_generator is really the main function im using to get the value, that was its name when I found it on an example here. In order to use it I created get_data_value() that sets the base data and loops to get the value. I don't think I could get the value before doing value = item_generator(d,data_name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's worth pointing out you have a bug here:**

```
for _ in item_generator(d,data_name):
    return (_)
```

This is an important case to be aware of, because the `return` statement here only returns once. Therefore, this `for` loop only runs for the first iteration, and only returns the first `yield` result - i.e. only the first occurrence of the lookup key in the `json_data`.

You can fix it using generator (or iterable) unpacking into a `list`, as below:

```py
def get_data_value(data, data_name):
    d = data['test']
    return [*item_generator(d, data_name)]


def item_generator(json_input, lookup_key):
    if isinstance(json_input, dict):
        if lookup_key in json_input:
            yield {lookup_key: json_input[lookup_key]}
        else:
            for v in json_input.values():
                yield from item_generator(v, lookup_key)

    elif isinstance(json_input, list):
        for item in json_input:
            yield from item_generator(item, lookup_key)


json_data = {"test": [{"Tier1": [{"Tier1-Main-Title-1": [{"title": "main", "example": 400}]}]}, {"Tier2": []},
                      {"Tier3": [{"Example1-Sub1": 44, "title": "TEST2"}]}]}

print(get_data_value(json_data, 'title'))
```

Result:

```
[{'title': 'main'}, {'title': 'TEST2'}]
```

**Or, if you'd prefer not to call `get_data_value` at all:**

```
print(*item_generator(json_data['test'], 'title'))
```

Where passing the key `'test'` is optional, thanks to the function being recursive by nature.

The results are separated by a single space by default, but you can control the separator by passing the `sep` parameter to the print statement.

```
{'title': 'main'} {'title': 'TEST2'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I am missing something but why dont you just return what you want? Like this for example:

```
def get_data_value(data,data_name):
    d = data['test']
    print(item_generator(d,data_name))
    for _ in item_generator(d,data_name):
        return (_)

def item_generator(json_input, lookup_key):
    if isinstance(json_input, dict):
        for key, value in json_input.items():
            if key == lookup_key:      
                yield {key:value} 
            else:
                yield from item_generator(value, lookup_key)
    elif isinstance(json_input, list):
        for item in json_input:
            yield from item_generator(item, lookup_key)


json_data = { "test": [ { "Tier1": [ { "Tier1-Main-Title-1": [ { "title": "main", "example": 400 } ] } ] }, { "Tier2": [] }, { "Tier3": [ { "Example1-Sub1": 44 } ] } ] }

print(get_data_value(json_data,'title'))
```

Also if you have multiple instances of "title" in different sub-objects and you want all of them back maybe in a list this can also work:

```
def get_data_value(data, data_name):
    d = data["test"]
    results = []
    for item in item_generator(d, data_name):
        results.append(item)
    return results


def item_generator(json_input, lookup_key):
    if isinstance(json_input, dict):
        for key, value in json_input.items():
            if key == lookup_key:
                yield {key: value}
            else:
                yield from item_generator(value, lookup_key)
    elif isinstance(json_input, list):
        for item in json_input:
            yield from item_generator(item, lookup_key)


json_data = {
    "test": [
        {
            "Tier1": [
                {
                    "Tier1-Main-Title-1": [
                        {"title": "main", "example": 400},
                        {"title": "example2"},
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {"Tier2": []},
        {
            "Tier3": [
                {"Example1-Sub1": 44},
                {"AnotherExample": 9856, "title": "example3"},
            ]
        },
    ]
}

print(get_data_value(json_data, "title"))
```

This returns: `[{'title': 'main'}, {'title': 'example2'}, {'title': 'example3'}]`